# App "crashes" when quit while in background

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1 and am encountering a very bizarre crash in my application. My testing is being done on a real device, specifically the iPhone 6 running iOS 9.1.

**Scenario 1** - I am using my app like normal, I double tap the home button and swipe up on my app to quit it. In this case, Xcode goes from "Running [app name] on [device name]" to "Finished running [app name] on [device name]" just as it should.

**Scenario 2** - I am using my app like normal, I double tap the home button and go to a *different* running app while my app is still running in the background. Then, I double tap the home button once more and go *back* to my app. Finally I double tap the home button and quit my app. In this case, Xcode goes from "Running [app name] on [device name]" to "Finished running [app name] on [device name]" just as it should.

**Scenario 3** - I am using my app like normal, I double tap the home button and go to a *different* running app while my app is still running in the background. Then, I double tap the home button once more and quit *my* app (not the app being currently used) and Xcode treats this as a crash. The line `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` gets highlighted red and says "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL". In the crash log, all it says is "(lldb)" and the [breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQMR5.png) of what went wrong under thread 1 does not highlight any of my own code. I also created a blank application, tried these scenarios, and was greeted by the same behavior and an identical thread breakdown.

How can I fix, or even begin to understand, what's going wrong here? According to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) I may be dealing with a "watch-dog timeout", granted the source is possibly outdated. This isn't really affecting my users nor the application in a negative way, but I do believe these "crashes" get reported to App Analytics. Some days I see a relatively large amount of crashes being reported and I would like to eliminate this particular occurrence so I can know how many people are experiencing functional crashes which actually affect the user experience.  Any input is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then, I double tap the home button once more and quit my app (not the app being currently used) and Xcode treats this as a crash

It *is* a crash. You have killed the app dead. That what the SIGKILL is telling you. This is normal.

Comment: But it does not occur solely when I kill the app, only when I kill the app while it is not the current app being used.

Comment: Because at that time it has gone into the background and has been suspended. That was not the case with any of your other examples.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do? I presume these crashes do get included in App Analytics crash reports?

Comment: I wouldn't presume anything if I were you. But I'm telling you that the way the device console is responding to your actions is normal. If you doubt it, try it with a new clean project.